# Fleek CLI Error: "No api key found" despite FLEEK_API_KEY being set in .env file

Tags: dapps, ipfs, cli, nextjs

I am currently working on hosting a Next.js app for an NFT marketplace on IPFS using Fleek. I've followed the steps to install the Fleek CLI using `npm i -g @fleekhq/cli`, built the app with npm run build, and initialized Fleek using fleek site:init.

However, during the initialization process, I encountered the following prompt:

```
? Which team you wanna use? Please input the teamId. e012xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
...fetching list of sites for team: e0128b28-76e4-4df9-afd6-66c0cae45662
    Error: No api key found. Generate a Fleek Hosting api key in the Fleek app and make it available to the Fleek CLI
    by creating an environment variable named FLEEK_API_KEY with a value corresponding to the generated api key.
```

Here's what I've done to address this issue:

> Installed Fleek CLI: I used the command npm i -g @fleekhq/cli to install the Fleek CLI globally.

> Built the App: I successfully built the Next.js app using the command `npm run build`.

> Set FLEEK_API_KEY: I've set the FLEEK_API_KEY environment variable in my `.env` file with the following content:

```
FLEEK_API_KEY=<MY_FLEEK_API_KEY>
```

Despite having the FLEEK_API_KEY environment variable properly set in my .env file, I'm still encountering the "No api key found" error during the initialization process. Is there something I might be missing or a step I need to take to ensure that the Fleek CLI recognizes the FLEEK_API_KEY from the .env file? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.